# Manhwa where the main character begins as a child training with a master in the mountains and killing monsters

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manhwa only had 1 chapter when I accidentally found it months ago (probably promotional chapter).

The story starts with the main character as a child with a long hair. At first I thought the main character was female due to his face but he was revealed as a male when he is meditating in waterfall shirtless. There was an old man that trains him for years in secluded area or mountain (I forgot most of its settings sorry).

Every time the main character shows an achievement like killing a monster, his master kills many more than him. After many years, the old man wants the main character to explore the world and gives some money to the main character. I think it also has also tournament in the preview.